# Is armbian for bananapi pro lacking luks support?

Tags: luks, armbian, bananapi

I have a bananapi **pro** and run armbian on it. I tried stable, testing and experimental (in that order) all with the same result. When I try

```
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda1 ext_crypt
```

I get

```
Enter passphrase for /dev/sda1: 
device-mapper: reload ioctl on  failed: No such file or directory
Failed to setup dm-crypt key mapping for device /dev/sda1.
Check that kernel supports aes-xts-plain64 cipher (check syslog for more info).
```

syslog:

```
May  4 20:53:19 localhost kernel: [78739.635960] device-mapper: table:
254:0: crypt: Error allocating crypto tfm May  4 20:53:19 localhost
kernel: [78739.635973] device-mapper: ioctl: error adding target to
table
```

I may want to add: The device in question (/dev/sda1) was luks formated and used on a bananapi (plain, not pro) before.

Do I have to compile my own kernel? Why is it, that I cannot open this device?

Comment: I suspect armbian doesn't have much of a presence here (there are only a handful of questions). You may be better off asking at the forums: https://forum.armbian.com/

Comment: Thank you! That actually solved my problem. I found the post https://forum.armbian.com/index.php?/topic/4136-bananapi-m1-crypto-issue-after-update/#comment-30420 recommending a dowgrade of two packages.